# SQL Wrap that query into another query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query that counts the occurrences of a record.

```
SELECT`seller_id`, COUNT(`seller_id`)
as Products_selling
FROM `Producs`
GROUP by `seller_id` 
ORDER BY Products_selling DESC
```

| Seller ID | Producs selling |
| --- | --- |
| id 1 | 5 |
| id 2 | 2 |

In this table there is an id field. I would like to inner join with the matching table.

```
SELECT name_seller, Producs.seller_id, model, Brand
FROM seller INNER JOIN producs
ON seller.seller_id=producs.seller_id
ORDER BY seller_id ASC
```

I would therefore like to count how many products the sellers sell and associate the seller's id to the other table with the name in a single query

I have made several attempts without success

```
SELECT name_seller COUNT(name_seller) FROM (
    SELECT name_seller, producs.seller_id, model, Brand
    FROM seller INNER JOIN producs
    ON seller.seller_id=producs.seller_id
    ORDER BY name_seller ASC
) as unit
```

Answer (score 1):

Join your original query with the `seller` table, rather than doing the join in the subquery.

```
SELECT s.name_seller, p.products_selling
FROM seller AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT `seller_id`, COUNT(*) AS products_selling
    FROM `Producs`
    GROUP by `seller_id` 
) AS p ON p.seller_id = s.seller_id
ORDER BY p.products_selling DESC
```

You can also group after joining the two tables:

```
SELECT s.name_seller, COUNT(*) AS products_selling
FROM seller AS s
JOIN Producs AS p ON p.seller_id = s.seller_id
GROUP BY s.seller_id
ORDER BY products_selling DESC
```

This might not be as efficient, so benchmark it when deploying.

Comment: I think that `seller.seller_id` is unique. In this case the subquery is obviously excess, and we may join then group.

Comment: I think it's often more efficient to group before joining. Logically they're equivalent, but the query optimizer might not always get it right.

Comment: *I think it's often more efficient to group before joining.* Depends on the rows amount and indices presence. See the model: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZtxUjdBw Vary the amount of rows in each table (try 10-1000 in `seller` and 100-1000000 in `Producs`) and look at the execution times. Of course, another columns presence (row size) will effect too.